# OpenCV boundingRect2f in python?

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

In OpenCV the function `boundingRect2f` ([see here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/db/dd6/classcv_1_1RotatedRect.html#a5e2a16189afb56b77218b2d60e094ebe)), returns the bounding rectangle with float precision. I would like to use this from Python, but I can only find the `int`-version `cv2.boundingRect`.

Does anyone know if it is available from the Python wrapper?

**Note:**

This is my current code that currently only works with `int`-precision:

```
rot_rect = (self.center, (self.width, self.height), -self.angle)
bounding_rect_in_int_precision_only = cv.boundingRect(cv.boxPoints(rot_rect))
```

I am using OpenCV 4.1, which should have this method according to the linked documenation.

Comment: It's a member function of a class that is not exposed to Python (rotated rectangle is represented as a tuple in Python). So... no.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Should have been clear to me, since I myself am using rotated rectangle as a tuple. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the [implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.1.0/modules/core/src/types.cpp#L203), it's fairly simple -- calculate the 4 corner points of the rotated rectangle, and then find minimum/maximum x/y coordinates. Should be fairly easy to port to Python.

Comment: Something like this (first draft): https://pastebin.com/m3DSSXmN (I'll test it out later and compare against C++ code, then write up a proper answer)